# AngularJs getting the url from which redirected to current

Tags: angularjs, redirect

Is there a way to get from which url we are redirected to current in AngularJs. I m writing a generic login. So I want to redirect to the the page from which I was directed to Login as soon as logged in successfully. In order to do that I want to get the Url from which I was redirected to here(Current/MyLogin) inside my controller.I have injected $location to my controller. Any one can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shared any code so, I am just showing you how you can achieve you goal.

Yes you can get that using either events `$locationChangeStart` `$locationChangeSuccess`

> ### $locationChangeStart
>
> - Broadcasted before a URL will change.
> - This change can be prevented by calling `preventDefault` method of the event. See `$rootScope.Scope` for more details about event object. Upon successful change `$locationChangeSuccess` is fired.
> - The `newState` and `oldState` parameters may be defined only in HTML5 mode and when the browser supports the HTML5 History API.

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart',function(event, absNewUrl, absOldUrl){
    console.log('start', event, absNewUrl, absOldUrl);
});
```

> ### $locationChangeSuccess
>
> - Broadcasted after a URL was changed.
> - The `newState` and `oldState` parameters may be defined only in HTML5 mode and when the browser supports the HTML5 History API.

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess',function(event, absNewUrl, absOldUrl) {
    console.log('success', event, absNewUrl, absOldUrl);
});
```

## See also

- [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

---

Another way is

> Event `$stateChangeSuccess` fired once the state transition is complete.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
  //fromState is what you are looking for 
});
```

## See also

- [ui-router wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)